# POST directly to Firebase from SAAS webhooks / callbacks?

Tags: firebase, transloadit

When dealing with SAAS callbacks aka webhooks(?), it makes sense to me that I could avoid calling my nodeJS backend and instead have the SAAS post directly to Firebase.

If I curl or use Transloadit's notify_url tester, I get:
`{<br />
  "error" : "Unrecognized token 'transloadit': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN\n at [Source: java.io.StringReader@6218652a; line: 1, column: 12]"<br />
}<br />`

`curl -X POST --data 'transloadit={ "alanisawesome": { "name": "Alan Turing", "birthday": "June 23, 1912" } }' https://example.firebaseio.com/transloadit.json`

However if I POST without the 'transloadit=' (the params), it will work fine. Is there a way I could hack either firebase or SAAS' i.e. Transloadit, or should I just give up and pass through nodeJS?

Comment: Try taking out transloadit= when you curl against the Firebase URL. It accepts a valid json payload, and the transloadit= is not valid.

Comment: I can't because it's only an input box and they name it 'transloadit' but thanks anyway.

Comment: You can't put transloadit= into a JSON string; it's not valid JSON. Your curl command doesn't come from an input field. If there are additional constraints, you'll need to provide enough information to understand them before anybody can assist here.